# I want to update a text window with the time periodically in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, text, time, widget

I want to periodically update a text window with the current time at a rate of about 1 sec. Can't figure out how to periodically get time and update text window.  put a loop both before and after mainloop(). neither work.

```
# Siderial Time Calculation

from Tkinter import *
import time as tm
from time import strftime
from PyAstronomy import pyasl
import datetime

root = Tk()

st=strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000 %Z", tm.gmtime())
print 'st',st[17:25]

mytext = Text(root, background='#101010', foreground="#D6D6D6", borderwidth=18, relief='sunken',width=16, height=5 )
mytext.insert(END, st)
mytext.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

With infinite loop before mainloop Text widget does not appear.  With infinite loop after mainloop widget appears but no text window update.

Comment: There are lots of questions on this site related to creating clocks and timers in tkinter. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

This code use `after()` to run function with delay.

Because `after()` runs function only once (or rather it sends this function to `mainloop` which executes it only once) so you have to use it again and again in executed function. You can do it at beginning or at the end of this function.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

# --- functions ---

def update_time():
    # run again after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, update_time)

    st = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000 %Z", time.gmtime())
    print 'st:', st[17:25]

    #mytext.delete(0, 'end')
    mytext.insert('end', st)
    mytext.insert('end', '\n')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

mytext = tk.Text(root)
mytext.grid(row=0, column=0)

# run first time without delay
update_time()

# run first time with delay
#root.after(1000, update_time)

root.mainloop()
```